# ProgressDialog show() throws "Unable to add window" error

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am trying to user ProgressDialog to create a "Loading" display in the screen during network request.

I set it up like this: ("LoginActivity" is the name of my activity)

```
ProgressDialog loading;
loading = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);


signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                email = editName.getText().toString();
                password = editPassword.getText().toString();
                if (isEmailValid(email)) {
                    if (isPasswordValid(password)) {
                        loading.setMessage("Checking");
                        loading.show();                     //fails here, line 265
                        String action = "signIn";
                        getUserStatus(email,password,action);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password > 5 characters & have 1 number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter Valid Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

But I get this error:

```
2020-09-28 10:29:10.409 19042-19042/com.example.application1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.application1, PID: 19042
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1068)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:409)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:340)
        at com.example.application1.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:265)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2020-09-28 10:29:10.430 1371-1973/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '650eeb4 com.example.application1/com.example.application1.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Try passing getApplicationContext() instead of loginactivity.this

Comment: @Wini Did not work. Same error.